# JVM args setting for Codehaus jetty ant plugin

Tags: embedded-jetty

When starting jetty using Codehaus jetty ant plugin, how can I pass JVM args?

Answer (score 0):

still looking, myself, but you can always set the ANT_OPTS - i.e.

export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx1000m -Xms1000m"; ant jetty

not pretty, I know, but best I've found so far.